# Chocolate pancakes using melted chocolate

Tags: substitutions, chocolate, pancakes, cocoa

I have a friend who wants to make American-style chocolate pancakes for breakfast in Mother's Day.
That's alright and there are plenty of recipes laying around, but the thing is she would like to use some bar chocolate she has laying around, melting it and using it in preparing the batter instead of using cocoa.

I've tried to convince her to use the chocolate for other purposes (chocolate chips, making ganache or syrup for the pancakes, using it in other recipes or otherwise saving it for later), but she seems... unbending.

I've found only a couple recipes using melted chocolate in the batter (and they don't have many reviews), but a multitude of well tested/reviewed recipes using cocoa powder.
Is there a reasonable way to adapt recipes using cocoa powder, or should I just tell her it's helpless?

EDIT: The chocolate is milk chocolate (which in my country must contain at minimum 25% cocoa solids), but does not divulge its percentage. Its ingredients are sugar, whole milk powder, cocoa butter, cocoa liquor, vegetable shortening, lactose, cocoa powder, anhydrous milk fat, emulsifiers (soy lecithin and polyglycerol polyricinoleate) and flavouring.
Nutritional information in the image below (quantities per 25g of chocolate).

[image]

Comment: What type of bar chocolate is it (what % cacao) and how sweetened?

Comment: If she seems unbending, how is this your responsibility? We all know it wouldn't work so well to use melted chocolate..

Comment: @NSGod I've added information on the question.

GeorgeM, it's absolutely not my responsibility, I'm just trying to help if at all reasonable.

Comment: Looking at the type of chocolate she wants to use it's not even high quality chocolate. These aren't going to be good pancakes no matter how you do it. So if I were you, I wouldn't get involved.

Comment: Did your friend say why she wanted to use melted chocolate? Did she say she wanted to use that exact chocolate, and if so, did she say why? I agree with aris's assessment that the presented chocolate is not a high quality variety (based on the presence of vegetable shortening), so I wonder if your friend wants to take advantage of some special characteristic of the bar that is hard to find in other products.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps she could make "regular" pancakes and use the melted chocolate candy bar in place of traditional syrup?

Imagine, a stack of hot pancakes with melted chocolate poured over them... perhaps a fresh strawberry on the side.  oh my! I might have to make some for myself!